# Software to record videos on iphone that doesn't result on video sizes of tremendous sizes

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, video

I often record videos with my phone that are 30 to 1hour 30 minutes long. However, the file sizes that result are ridiculously large. I want a way to still be able to record videos of that length and reduce the size a lot. If quality of the video has to be sacrificed, so be it.

The only way I could think of solving this is by downloading some kind of app that does that.

To tailor answer to my specific use case, consider a description of the type of things I record:

I will use it to record talks, presentations, lectures, etc. I don't need anything that is too crazy.

However, I do have some minimum requirements I expect from the app.

1. I want to be able to control the quality of the video. If I record 30 minutes to 1 hour 30 minute talks, I don't need it to be HD. Just enough so that I can record the slides or the whiteboard/blackboard. This requirement is to control the SIZE of the video. Videos that are 8 GBs of size or more than 5 GB of size are useless to me.
2. I need to be able to control how I zoom in and out of my videos. For example, if I can't control very granularly how I close my video is, then it might not be useful.
3. I also need to be able to send these videos to my actual macbook computer somehow. Connecting it and then downloading it to the macbook pro is a great option.

Using the built in app is terrible for me because the videos are of ridiculous sizes (ranging from 5 to 10 GB size). I just need them to be much smaller and still be able to save them on my computer (and potentially upload them to youtube).

I also downloaded the app VideoCamara+ and its great that it lets me control the quality, but it seems limited in its ability to zoom (it only has two modes of closeness as far as I know).

I have also tried moviePro8 but it seems that its low resolutions results in really bad videos (as far as I can tell). VideoCamara+ has the same setting for low resolutions and its videos are not as bad.

Comment: we usually deal with problems and no so much with shopping advices. What was the result from your search?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I see what you mean. The problem I am having is that I record something and its too large of a size. Thats the problem. I couldn't care less how to solve the problem. Could be by buying an app or downloading something free. I don't really want advice "on shopping". Either there is a way to record videos on iphones which leads to small video sizes or not. If you think I could tailor my question to address my specific problem, I would be happy. I agree, that it sounds like a shopping question, but thats not what its meant for, I just couldn't think how else to solve this issue.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I updated my question, is that better? Or how do you recommend me to write my question? Are there any other solutions other than downloading an app to solve my problem?

Comment: related question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/apple-ios-record-videos-via-ipod-touch-reduce-video-size

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do.

I use the VLC player almost exclusively since it can play anything.

Since you want to save space and eventually download to youtube I would recommend a 2 step process.

First record it in high quality.

Then use a small app called Flv Crunch to convert "any" file format to flv type that is enormous size reduction and compatible with youtube.

It is very easy to use and control the settings.

[image: vlc]

[Convert files between flv, mpeg 1/2/4, 3gp, mp3, m4a, wmv, wma, avi, mkv, aiff, and others.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/4y43eeq4wx32bzh/Flv+Crunch+1.5.1.zip)

Then delete the original (ok that was 3 steps :)

why do it this way?

I learned the hard way that once the event is over you are stuck with what ever quality you used to record. Thus I recommend you always record in high quality, since it is easy to reduce the file size to quality you want as end product.

For example you recorded something that needs to be magnified or altered for clarity, that would not be possible any more if recording in low quality.

[About Flash Video Format:](http://www.motionelements.com/blog/articles/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-5-most-common-video-file-formats)

> FLV files are videos that are encoded by Adobe Flash software. They
>   can be played via the Adobe Flash Player, web browser plugins or one
>   of several third party programs. Since virtually everyone has the
>   player installed on their browsers, it has become the most common
>   online video viewing platform used on the Web today. As almost all
>   video sharing sites such as Youtube stream videos in Flash,
>   practically all browsers support and are compatible with the Flash
>   Video format and can play the video with ease. In addition to being an
>   online video viewing format, the Flash Video format is also what many
>   video-sharing sites convert videos to, from formats that were uploaded
>   by their users in something other than Flash.
>
> This is because videos in the FLV format remain in high quality even
>   after compression to a smaller file size, which means that the videos
>   on the Web load quickly and won’t spend a lot of time using up
>   bandwidth.
>
> Some notable users of the Flash Video are Youtube, Yahoo! Video, VEVO,
>   Hulu and Myspace among many others.

Comment: I wouldn't convert to FLV. It is not that widely supported (it won't run on iOS without downloading an app that explicitly supports it, for example). I would down-convert into the same format that the files already are, just reduce the resolution and audio fidelity.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Pro Camera 8](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/procamera-8/id694647259?mt=8) for video recording. You can reduce the resolution of the video down to 640x480 and 30 FPS, which should result in significantly smaller videos than using the default Camera app.

Pro Camera also has a zoom slider (which is disabled by default) that can do digital zoom up to 6x. Videos save to the Camera Roll and can be synced with your Mac easily or shared via any method that the Photos app supports.

Comment: Are the only options HQ VGA, HD 729, HD+ 1080? What does HQ VGA even mean?

Comment: I think HQ does mean 640x480 after taking a closer look at the user manual...

Comment: VGA was originally a display but has come to mean an analog graphics standard, synonymous with 640x480.